# Is there a way to create a table with EF6 using a DbModelBuilder directly?

Tags: c#, postgresql, oracle, entity-framework-6

I'm searching for a way to create a table in my database directly for a temporary entity. Since the database can be defined via connection string the syntax of the create statement could be different between postgres an Oracle for instance - therefore I cannot write it as a plain text command.

Does anybody know a way to achive this from an Entity / DbModelBuilder / DbModel / DbCompiledModel within EF6?  I have to mention, that I cannot use EF Core.

This is my setup so far:

```
public class TMPEntity
{
  public TMPEntity();

  public string EntityId{ get; set; }
}

var modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();

// set default schema
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SCHEMA");

// Create Table in this schema
modelBuilder.Entity<TMPEntity>().ToTable(tableName: "TMPEntityTable", schemaName: "SCHEMA");

modelBuilder.Entity<TMPEntity>().HasKey(
h => new
{
  h.EntityId
});

var ctx = modelBuilder
.Build(context.Database.Connection)
.Compile();
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with. Not the best solution I guess, but at least a working one until further advice :-)

Since I did not manage it to generate valid SQL from the EdmModel class or the DBModel I created a DbMigration class, which creates the table now. Not as smart as the ModelBuilder approach, but as I mentioned - working:

```
internal class CreateSingleTableMigration: DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "\"SCHEMA\".\"TMPEntityTable\"",
                c => new
                {
                    // Single column
                    EntityId= c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150)
                    // Further columns go in here ...
                })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.EntityId /*Combined PK goes here*/ });
        }
    }
```

Now the question was, how to generate and execute valid SQL from that with the selected IDbProvider. Since I want to reuse an existing DbContext, all required information are available in this class.

```
// If database exists
if (context.Database.Exists())
{
    // Get the corresponding DbProviderServices the Provider of the current Connection has to offer
    var serv = DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(context.Database.Connection);

    // Get the provider manifest token
    var tkn = serv.GetProviderManifestToken(context.Database.Connection);

    // Get the PropertyInfo of the internal "Operations" property
    var prop = typeof(InitializeHistorizationMigration)
                 .GetProperty("Operations", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // If Property "operations" was found
    if (prop != null)
    {
        // get SQL Generator for the current provider
        var generator = new Configuration().GetSqlGenerator(FWLPDataContext.Provider);

        // Create instance of the CreateTable-Migration
        var tmpMig= new CreateSingleTableMigration();
        // Apply it, so property "Operation" is filled
        tmpMig.Up();

        // Get the operations as a List of single MigrationOperation
        var operations = (prop.GetValue(tmpMig) as IEnumerable<MigrationOperation>).ToList();

        // Generate SQL and run it against the database using the DbContext Connection
        foreach (var item in generator.Generate(operations, tkn))
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item.Sql);
        }
    }
}
```

With postgres the execution of the SQL script generated an error: SqlState: 3F000
MessageText: no schema has been selected to create in

That is why I added the schema in the CreateSingleTableMigration class, setting the Search Path within the connection string did not help.

If you have better approaches or ideas on how to optimize that- let me know!